# Android - Storage Access Framework - Uri into local file

Tags: java, android, storage-access-framework

I am using `Storage Access Framework(SAF)` in my app. In order to scan a file(photo or document) i need send a local file path trough an API. I've managed to setup the `SAF` correctly, and now when a user chooses a file and i am getting a Uri as it supposed to be.

As it seems the Uri is a key for the cloud and not a local file.

The Uri value looks like that:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:11862
```

How can i convert this Uri into a local file? Should i download the file from the cloud? How can i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As it seems the Uri is a key for the cloud and not a local file.

The `Uri` is an opaque reference to a piece of content. You have no way of knowing where the data is, nor should you care.

> How can i convert this Uri into a local file?

Ideally, you don't. Ideally, you "scan a file(photo or document)" using some library that supports an `InputStream`. In that case, you use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get the stream to pass to the library.

If your library does not support `InputStream` as a data source, you will need to use `openInputStream()` yourself, using Java I/O to make a copy of the content as a file in the filesystem, for you to pass to the library.

Comment: What about when a library only accepts a File or an absolute path to a directory?

Comment: @masterwok: I'd start by pointing the library authors to [this five-year-old blog post of mine](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/08/07/for-android-apis-think-streams-not-files.html) asking library authors to think in terms of streams, not files. And, until they improve their API, you would need to use the `InputStream` from my answer to copy the content to a file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`). Then, pass the path to that file to the library.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. However, I'm not sure I understand how this would work for directories. The library I'm using has a parameter for download location. It then downloads one or more files to the provided location. If the developer of the library were to accept a Uri with a content scheme for some parent location, then could they create multiple "files" at that location using ContentResolver and InputStream somehow?

Comment: @masterwok: If the library is Android-specific, and you got the `Uri` via `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, they could in theory create whatever they need inside of there. The "tree" `Uri` is the Storage Access Framework equivalent of a directory, so the library could use `DocumentFile` and `ContentResolver` to create documents inside of that tree. Or, have the library download the stuff to a directory that you control, then you worry about transferring the content to the document tree. Or, skip the Storage Access Framework and stick with the filesystem.

Comment: Awesome, I think I see how it comes together now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can read directly from the underlying file, with random access, under the following conditions:

- The URI points to a local file, you can check this comparing the URI authority with the value `com.android.externalstorage.documents`;
- You have both read and write access to the URI.

```
ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = getContext().getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(documentUri, "rw");
FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
FileChannel channel = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor).getChannel();
```

Store the FileDescriptor somewhere as long as you keep the FileChannel open: if that object gets garbage collected the channel will be no longer able to access the file.